# How to override the Search.php using preference in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, overrides, preference

I am not able to override the Search.php file by using preference in magento 2.3.4.
Below is the my di.xml file. Please anybody can check the below code.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\Search\Search" type="Candere\Sortfix\Search\Search" />
</config>
```

Comment: did you run di:compile

Comment: I run the setup:upgrade and di:compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only specify preferences for classes that get instantiated. From what  I see, the class `Magento\Framework\Search\Search` does not get instantiated. It is only extended by the class `Magento\Search\Model\Search` which gets instantiated. (it is a preference for `Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface`).

You can either add a preference for this model

```
<preference for="Magento\Search\Model\Search" type="Candere\Sortfix\Search\Search" />
```

or you can add a preference for `Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface`

```
<preference for="Magento\Search\Api\SearchInterface" type="Candere\Sortfix\Search\Search" />
```